# Collection of objects of an specific class in PHP

Tags: php, collections

I would like to have an array/object-like collection in which the elements are objects of an specific class (or derived from it). In Java I would do something like the following:

```
private List<FooClass> FooClassBag = new ArrayList<FooClass>();
```

I know that this could and will tightly couple some components of my application, but I have been wondering for a while now how to do that in a proper way.

The only way to do it I can think now is to create a class implementing `Countable`, `IteratorAggregate`, `ArrayAccess`... and forcing a way to add elements of just one class, but is this the best way to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it. PHP doesn't provide a very easy way to do it, but you could implement your own list class that only accepts classes of a given type.

Comment: you want to do generic programming in php ? forget it...

Comment: Extend SPLObjectStorage and implement a custom attach() method that validates the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation, but I wouldn't ever use such a structure.

```
<?php
class TypedList implements \ArrayAccess, \IteratorAggregate {
    private $type;

    private $container = array();

    public function __construct($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->container[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (!is_a($value, $this->type)) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException();
        }
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->container);
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
class MySubClass extends MyClass {}

$class_list = new TypedList('MyClass');
$class_list[] = new MyClass('foo');
$class_list[] = new MySubClass('bar');
try {
    $class_list[] = 'baz';
} catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {

}
foreach ($class_list as $value) {
    echo $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Even though the proposed structure seems to work nicely, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @DiegoAgulló There's no point trying to force statically-typed data structures on a dynamically-typed language. And there's also no sense in making PHP make sense.

Comment: Feels weird to post an answer for something you are stating you do not recommend doing. Either there is a better way, post that, or perhaps just suggest there is no good way to do it?